# Node-express promise chaining and common catch statement

Tags: node.js, express, promise, google-cloud-firestore, passport.js

I have a code where I am making multiple to database

```
 FirebaseHelper.getDataFromDB("users", profileSort.email )
    .then(response => {
        if (response.exists) {
          FirebaseHelper.updateDataInDb("authentication", profileSort.email, TokenToStore)
          .then(() => {
            console.log("here")
               //User signs in, check if we have tokens for meetup, eventbrite
            FirebaseHelper.getDataFromDB("authenticat", profileSort.email)
            .then(response => {
              //if yes, store them in session
              if (response.exists)   {
                req.session.contextToken = response.data()
                  if (req.session.contextToken["meetupAccessToken"]) profileSort["meetup"] = true
                  if (req.session.contextToken["meetupAccessToken"]) profileSort["eventbrite"] = true
              //Replace the token with currret store token
              req.session.contextToken = {...req.session.contextToken, ...TokenToStore}
              }
              return done(null, profileSort)
            })
            .catch(error =>  {  done(error) })
          })
          .catch(error =>  done(error))
         } else {
        //adding user and storing authentication information
         FirebaseHelper.setDataToDb("users", profileSort.email, profileSort)
         .then(() => {
            FirebaseHelper.setDataToDb("authentication", profileSort.email, TokenToStore)
            .catch(error =>  done(error))
         })
         .catch(error =>  done(error))
          return done(null, profileSort)
        }
    })
  .catch(error =>  done(error))
}
```

While, this code works, there are just so many nested `.then()` statement inside each other

Additionally there are so many catch statement just returning errors.

Now, While this code sort of works but it also looks very untidy.

Can someone help me in figuring out how I can make above code neat and tidy? Probably by removing unwanted `.catch()` statement

Ps: This is inside passport strategy

Comment: Sounds like `done` is a callback function passed to the function that contains all of the above code, is that correct? Is returning a Promise instead OK? (it'd probably be a lot more elegant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the process of signing in takes a moderate amount of code, consider putting it into its own self-contained function that returns a `Promise`. Do the same for adding a user, and then you can use a *single* `.catch` at the end, if there's an error, by returning all the Promises so that they're chained together properly, avoiding the promise-as-callback anti-pattern:

```
FirebaseHelper.getDataFromDB("users", profileSort.email )
  .then(({ exists }) => (
    exists
    ? updateData()
    : addUser()
  ))
  .then((profileSort) => {
    done(null, profileSort);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    done(err);
  });

  function updateData() {
  return FirebaseHelper.updateDataInDb("authentication", profileSort.email, TokenToStore)
  //User signs in, check if we have tokens for meetup, eventbrite
    .then(() => {
      return FirebaseHelper.getDataFromDB("authenticat", profileSort.email);
    })
    .then(response => {
    //if yes, store them in session
    if (response.exists) {
      req.session.contextToken = response.data();
      if (req.session.contextToken.meetupAccessToken) {
        profileSort.meetup = true;
        profileSort.eventbrite = true;
      }
      //Replace the token with currret store token
      req.session.contextToken = {...req.session.contextToken, ...TokenToStore}
    }
    return profileSort;
  });
}
function addUser() {
  //adding user and storing authentication information
  return FirebaseHelper.setDataToDb("users", profileSort.email, profileSort)
    .then(() => {
      return FirebaseHelper.setDataToDb("authentication", profileSort.email, TokenToStore)
  })
    .then(() => profileSort);
  return done(null, profileSort)
}
```

It would be even better if the containing function returned a `Promise` rather than accepting a `done` callback - promises are much nicer to work with than callbacks, after all:

```
function doStuff() {
  return FirebaseHelper.getDataFromDB("users", profileSort.email )
    .then(({ exists }) => (
      exists
      ? updateData()
      : addUser()
    ));
  // ...
```

Then, rather than

```
doStuff((err, profileSort) => {
  // ...
```

you can do

```
doStuff()
  .then((profileSort) => {
    // handle success
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  })
```

Using `async`/`await` instead of `.then`s can make the code even shorter, don't know if your environment supports that though.

Comment: Since **in your code**, we aren't chaining promise, Why not use `Promise.all`?

Comment: All the promises in my code *are* being chained - see how every call of a `Promise` is `return`ed, so that the next `.then` can consume it? Your code is treating Promises like callbacks (no chaining), which kind of defeats the purpose

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Node 8 or higher you could use async functions to make this a little more verbose/readable and wrap it in a trycatch block so you don't have to chain the catch to each thenable promise:

```js
async function login() {
  try {
    const users = await FirebaseHelper.getDataFromDB("users", profileSort.email);

    if (users.exists) {
      await FirebaseHelper.updateDataInDb("authentication", profileSort.email, TokenToStore);
      const authenticat = await FirebaseHelper.getDataFromDB("authenticat", profileSort.email);

      if (authenticat.exists) {
        req.session.contextToken = response.data();
        if (req.session.contextToken["meetupAccessToken"]) profileSort["meetup"] = true;
        if (req.session.contextToken["meetupAccessToken"]) profileSort["eventbrite"] = true;
        req.session.contextToken = {...req.session.contextToken, ...TokenToStore};

        return done(null, profileSort);
      }
    } else {
      await FirebaseHelper.setDataToDb("users", profileSort.email, profileSort);
      await FirebaseHelper.setDataToDb("authentication", profileSort.email, TokenToStore);
      return done(null, profileSort);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return done(error);
  }
}
```